Find out which translation stage caused an MMU fault exception
(I'm relatively new to aarch64 and to ARM in general, so sorry if this is a dumb question.)
When handling a Data Abort exception (raised in EL1, and taken to EL2 where my hypervisor is running) I need to discern if the MMU fault happened in stage 1 or stage 2. I've been searching the manual for some hours now and I'm unable to find a field that gives me this info. I need to know this before I can use other fields like S1PTW or HPFAR to get further info.
I thought that maybe the stage can be inferred from the combination of target and source ELs, since intuitively I'd expect an MMU fault exception to be taken to the EL that controls the translation regime + stage where it occurs. But the closest I've seen in the manual is IYMZWZ:

When an MMU fault is generated and reported as an Instruction Abort or Data Abort, the Exception level that the exception is taken to depends on the translation regime and translation stage that caused the fault.

But I wasn't able to find anything explaining this dependency. And even then, IIUC exceptions can be rerouted to other ELs so not sure how robust such an inference is?
